# TableView in UIPopOverView Issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I have a issue in UIPopover, I have added UITableView in UIPopover

When I am running its running good in iOS7.* as below:

[image: Image 1]

But while I am running in iOS8, it display as below:

[image]

My code is as below

```
CustomPopOverViewController *viewControllerForPopover =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomPopOverVC"];

viewControllerForPopover.delegate = self;

int setTimeFlag = [[[selectedModuleProgram objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] valueForKey:kProgram_Mst_Program_Time_Flag] intValue];

if (setTimeFlag == 1)
{
    [viewControllerForPopover setListType:kListType_AddProgramOptions];
    viewControllerForPopover.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(333, 453);
}
else
{
    [viewControllerForPopover setListType:kListType_AddProgramOptionsWOA];
    viewControllerForPopover.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(333, 382);
}

self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
self.popover.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomPopoverBackgroundView class];
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame
                              inView:anchor.superview
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

In my code **CustomPopOverViewController** is of my **UIViewController** and in that i have a tableview.

I have set a frame of tableview as below:

```
tblViewList.frame = CGRectMake(tblViewList.frame.origin.x, tblViewList.frame.origin.y, tblViewList.frame.size.width, (72*[arrData count]));
```

Don't get all option.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Is it possible preferredContentSize is (333, 453) on iOS 7 and (333, 382) on iOS 8?

Comment: Are your arrData count correct? It set your heigh as i see..

Comment: Yes, It is correct.. I debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution,

I just **disable** **autolayout** of view and i works fine.

I get to know while searching, **view.frame = cgrectmake(),** didnt work in ios8 if **autolayout** is enable..

Thank you.