# UIView frames wrong in viewDidLayoutSubviews after upgrade to Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, frame, xib

In each of my xibs it asked me what default device do I want to use. I chose iPhone 6 and updated the frames to the suggested ones. Now, any view that was affected in the viewWill or viewDidLayoutSubviews is messed up. They all have frames of `CGRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)`.

Here's my code:

```
self.headImage.layer.cornerRadius = ceilf(CGRectGetWidth(self.headImage.frame)/2);
self.headImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Wondering what's up with this and whether there is a solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: self.headImage.layer.cornerRadius = ceilf(CGRectGetWidth(self.headImage.frame)/2); ;
    self.headImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;      
// but the frame is wrong; it show CGRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)  in xib it's  height and width was 62 and 62;

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after the xcode 8 update. The second trigger on viewDidLayoutSubviews gives the correct frames though.

Comment: I am also facing same issue with Xcode 8.0

Comment: I resolved my issue by calling myOwniew.layoutIfNeeded() before getting the myOwniew frame

Answer (score 25):

I resolved my issue by calling

```
myOwnView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

before getting the `myOwnView.frame`

Comment: This works, but I am not sure why exactly this is required. I would assume that the layout pass is done before didLayoutSubviews callback.

Comment: This works for me as well, but I thought the whole point of viewDidLayoutSubviews() is so that the views are ALREADY laid out?

Comment: It seems that constraint-based views are still in the process of being laid out at the call of `didLayoutSubviews()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28622285/8653957 for more info.

Comment: Same problem here. A subview's .frame is {zero, zero} even though didLayoutSubviews has been called. I solved this by forcing a layout pass via setNeedsLayout() and then layoutIfNeeded(). l What a terrible API.

Comment: This also worked for me by calling it before layoutSubviews() rather than calling it in the layout overrides. I used it to subsequently get the size of a UIScrollView with dynamic contents. And yeah - wtf, Apple?

Answer (score 5):

If even viewDidLayoutSubviews gives you the wrong frame - calling **layoutIfNeeded** on layoutSubviews can do the trick!

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    yourView.layoutIfNeeded()
    setGradientForYourView()
```

}

Comment: Helped me with setting the contentSize of a UIScrollView according to the updated frame of the UIScrollView. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was happening to me when I was returning from a pushed `ViewController` and in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` frame was incorrect.

My view's `width constraint` was set to be proportional to parent view's width and there was no constant offsets. I replaced this proportionality constraint with `offset constraints` and frame is now calculated correctly.

This issue was on XCode 10, iOS 12, iPhone 6 Plus.