# UIView not adjusting size to match device

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

Update: I was able to fix my problem below by moving my code in init(coder) to layoutSubviews. Thanks for your input!

I have a view class that basically builds a chess board and has constraints to be 1:1 ratio and a certain number of points from other UI. In the init(coder), I am drawing the board spaces and then calling a function to draw the pieces from my controller.

However, when I run the simulator it will not load based on the device, only on what I currently have selected in Interface Builder.

As an example, I have iPhone 7 Plus selected in IB but run the simulator on iPhone 7 causing the board to go off the screen. If I select iPhone 7 in both IB and the simulator, it works fine.

I have been having difficulty finding an answer for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

[Board too big on iPhone 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh0xg.png)

[Because Storyboard set to iPhone 7 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyPdA.png)

The app first draws the spaces in the init(coder):

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let spaces: CGFloat = CGFloat(Constants.numberOfSpaces)

    spaceMargin = 16
    spaceWidth = (bounds.width - (spaces - 1) * spaceMargin) / spaces
    spaceHeight = spaceWidth
    pawnTop = bounds.height * (-3/304)
    pawnMargin = bounds.width * (1/304)
    pawnHeight = bounds.height * (48/304)
    pawnWidth = bounds.width * (44/304)

    pawnDict = [:]
    spaceDict = [:]

    for column in 0..<Constants.numberOfSpaces {
        for row in 0..<Constants.numberOfSpaces {
            let coordinate = try! Coordinate(column: column, row: row)
            drawSpace(at: coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is called by my controller:

```
func updateBoard() {

    guard let board = dataSource?.currentBoard() else {
        return
    }

    // Remove previous pawns
    for subview in subviews {
        if let pawnView = subview as? PawnView {
            pawnView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    pawnDict = [:]

    // Draw new pawns based on placement in board model
    for column in 0..<Constants.numberOfSpaces {
        for row in 0..<Constants.numberOfSpaces {
            let coordinate = try! Coordinate(column: column, row: row)
            let space = board.getSpace(coordinate)
            if space.hasPawn {
                drawPawn(at: coordinate)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you draw your spaces using autolayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is due to the fact that a `UIView` doesn't know it's bounds in `init`. Take a look at the view lifecycle [here](https://bradbambara.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/object-life-cycle-uiview/).  To solve your problem you have two options: use auto layout to draw your board - OR - wait until later in the view lifecycle draw it.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601742/autolayout-uiview-within-uiview-has-incorrect-frame)

Comment: This info is invaluable! Thanks for posting it! I was able to get it to work by moving my init code into layoutSubviews

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow. Checked! :)

Comment: You're getting it. Thanks!